# Parsec parse many question

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I need to create a parser for a programming language. So far it is 95% done, I'd say, except for a tiny detail.

The program written in this language has the following structure:

```
outputs
inputs
expressions
```

The requirement is that outputs cannot be mixed with inputs. For example:

```
x := output of int;
y := output of in;
.....
z := input of int;
t := input of in;
.....
expressions
```

I can parse a single output just fine but if I try to use (many1 output), to allow multiple outputs, it doesn't work because it tries to parse the inputs as outputs.

My main parser looks like this:

```
prog =
    do outs <- many1 output
       ins <- many1 input
       exs <- expressions
       eof
       return (Prog outs ins exs)
```

I know it seems easy but I tried a lot of stuff and just cannot get it to work. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your rule for output looks something like this:

```
output = do name <- ident
            string ":= output of"
            type <- ident
            char ';'
            return $ Out name type
```

and your input rule looks the same except with "input of", then the problem is that both rules start with an `ident` and since parsec doesn't backtrack automatically, it will just try to apply `output` first, consuming the `ident` and then fail when it can't match "output of".

To fix this you can just wrap `output` and `input` in `try`, i.e.

```
outs <- many1 (try output)
ins <- many1 (try input)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. That totally fixed it. I didn't realize that they both begin with an ident and it gets consumed by the output parser.

Answer (score 0):

While sepp2k's answer works, I'd personally want to encapsulate the backtracking inside the output and input parsers.

Although this adds code to the parsers it make them more robust:

```
output = do name <- try prefix
            type <- ident
            char ';'
            return $ Out name type
  where
    prefix = do name <- ident
                string ":= output of"
                return name
```

With Parsec, its generally best to avoid **try** except for Char Parsers and use left factoring to improve the grammar (**try** can make parsers very fragile). Unfortunately the grammar you are working is not particularly friendly to left factoring and in this case it is probably not worth bothering.